# Why is my Mongoose findAll method returning a 500 error ..?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here is my model / Schema. The create method works, but the "all" method will not.. It returns a 500..

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var DiSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, lowercase: true , required: true },
  photo: { type: String },
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  year: { type: Number},
  timestamp: { type : Date, default: Date.now },
  description: { type: String},
  location: { type: Array },
  social: {
    website: {type: String},
    facebook: {type: String },
    twitter: {type: String },
    instagram: {type: String }
  }
});

DiSchema.methods.create = function(o, cb){
  this.model.save(o, cb);
};

DiSchema.methods.all = function(o, cb){
  Di.find(o, cb);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Di', DiSchema);
```

Here is my controller:

```
'use strict';

var Di = require('../models/di');

exports.create = function(req, res){
  Di.create(req.body , function(err, di){
    console.log('req.body.di', req.body);
    res.send({di:di});
  });
};

exports.index = function(req, res){
  Di.all({}, function(err, dis){
    res.send({dis:dis});
  });
};
```

Routes:

```
var dis = require('../contollers/dis');
app.get('/dis', dis.index);
app.post('/dis', dis.create);
```

The create method works fine, but when I hit the get endpoint, with the index / all method -- I keep getting a 500.

I can put the query directly in the controller, and it works.

But, when I try to invoke it from the schema method -- it won't.

Am I using the methods wrong? Is my JS off?

---

**Update:**

if I put this code in the controller, it works:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  Di.find({}, function(err, dis) {
    if (!err){ 
        res.send(dis);
  };
});
};
```

Still interested in the original question of "why the method is not working from the model".

---

i've also tried this refactor in the model, to no avail:

```
DiSchema.methods.list = function(o, cb){
  this.model.find(o, cb);
};
```

&

```
DiSchema.methods.list = function(o, cb){
  this.model('Di').find(o, cb);
};
```

Comment: What does the exception that caused the 500 error contain? You should be able to debug this from there.

Comment: I'm not getting anything showing on the network in inspector tools. The only thing that shows the 500 is morgan -- in the terminal. I'll look further into debugging this.  If I put a console.log in the Distiller.all function (within the controller), it never gets hit, so it seems the function is not being invoked properly or is getting hung...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so a few things..

The model needed to be changed to a static method. A method of the model.

Also, the syntax needed to be changed.

```
DiSchema.statics.all = function(o, cb){
  this.model('Di').find(o, cb);
};
```

If anyone would like to give a better description in layman's as to why these two changes were needed -- i'll be happy to change ownership of the correct answer.